# how to toggle between KML files in Google Earth or toggle between sets of points

Tags: html, kml, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

so basically I have a KML file that I load up, and I have 2 different sets of points that I present on there. However, I want to be able to present one set at a time, I figured the simplest way to do this is to split the set into 2 different KML files, and then load the appropriate file depending on set, or if there is another way of doing this, it could work for me as well.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While kaliatech's answer is correct and useful, it is also a bit of overkill and harder to implement than [this approach](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#fetch_kml_(interactive,_checkboxes)). It is a Google example and toggles the loading of various KML files via checkboxes.

All you need to do is change the filenames of your kmls to red/yellow/green OR change to code to names more specific to your use - depending on how comfortable you feel and what ythe end result you want is.

Comment: Are you talking about the box in the top left corner, where I can click on the different files to come up, or another example that is within that box? Thanks

Comment: The link in this answer wasn't working originally due to how SO escapes parentheses.  It is fixed now, so click again. If it still doesn't work, I think @lifeIsGood is suggesting you check out the "Fetch KML (Interactive, Checkboxes)" example.  However, I don't see how that is any easier (it adds/removes kml rather than setting visibility of folders), but perhaps it will help you.

Comment: Gotcha, Thanks. I want to to also give that approach a shot, since as you pointed out, I don't really have any java-script experience, so maybe that example will be easier for me to understand.

Comment: A question I have is when I copy and paste that code from code playground into my Notepad++, and run it I would expect it to run like on that site, however the checkboxes don't show up, only the map does, am I using the wrong headers or closers? since they ar enot shown on the google code playground

Comment: perhaps the footer should have something else besides just calling the

   <div id="map3d" style="height:200px; width:400px;"></div>

Comment: Shahin - if you want to do a complete copy and paste, first click on the 'edit html' button - top right. Otherwise you are only seeing the relevant javascript. kaliatech - thanks for editing my link. Lastly, I mentioned this as being easier since it is easier to manage 2 separate KMLS. ie Doesn't require any hand editing of the KML (assigning id's)

Comment: I ended up doing it this method, and it worked out well pretty quick. Appreciate the help from both of you.

Answer (score 0):

There are number of ways to do this if you are familiar with JavaScript and can make use of the [Google Earth API](https://developers.google.com/earth/).

This is an example of hiding/showing a folder within a KML file if the folder has a known ID:

```
var showFolder = true;
google.earth.fetchKml(gePlugin, kmlUrl, function(rootKmlFeature) {
      if (rootKmlFeature) {

        var myFolderEl = rootKmlFeature.getElementById('#myFolderId');
        if (showFolder) {
            myFolderEl.setVisibility(true);
        }
        else {
            myFolderEl.setVisibility(false);
        }
      }
});
```

The root KmlFeature is always a KmlContainer which provides methods for looking up child elements. Note that it can be difficult to know whether or not you need to use "getElementById" or "getElementByUrl". The google documentation isn't particularly clear:

- https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/interface_kml_container

Once you have a reference to the folder (or relevant KmlFeature), you can set the visibility (and many other properties) dynamically in response to UI events or whatever.

---

**Edit** (after your comment)

The fetchKml callback (in the HTML) provides you with the loaded kmlObject. Depending on how you want to trigger the show/hide interaction, you probably want to store that kmlObject in a higher (perhaps global) scope. Then, when user presses button, or whatever, you can do something like this:

```
function displayPlacemark1(visible) {

  var baseUrl = 'https://sites.google.com/' + 'site/shahinkmlexamples/experiment/bombs12.kml';

  var placemark = kmlObject.getElementByUrl('#placemark1');
  placemark.setVisibility(visible);
}
```

Correspondingly, in your KML file,  you want to add an id attribute to the placemarks. i.e.

```
...
<Placemark id="placemark1">
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm trying the folders approach but I am not fully understanding how to go about it, I added my code, would the code segment you posted go in the kml file or the html file, i have it in the html file, but it seems to be wrong.

Comment: Placement of the JS code depends on how/when you want to trigger the visibility. It could go in your fetchKml callback function, or you could store a reference to the loaded kmlObject and then trigger visibility at some later time.  Correspondingly, you  also need to add an id attribute to each placemark in the KML file. I added some additional info/examples to my answer.

Comment: I just realized per your last edit, that you likely do not understand JavaScript. The code you pasted in per your edit belongs in the fetchKml callback of your initCB function.  The location you pasted it does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions above describe the Google Earth API approach with JavaScript.

The pure-KML solution is to add a radio button via a ListStyle to a Folder in your KML then have each set of points in a sub-folder or NetworkLink link. You can make one of the sets visible by default by adding *<visibility>0</visibility>* element on the other sub-folders you want not shown initially. Another trick is having an empty first feature with instructions in the name or description to select radio button to view the other sets. You can find this used in the [Google Maps Overlay in Google Earth](http://www.gelib.com/google-maps.htm).

*radioFolder* when specified for a Container, only one of the Container's items is visible at a time.

Here's example of KML using a *radioFolder* with two sets of Points:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>

    <Style id="rf">
      <ListStyle>
        <listItemType>radioFolder</listItemType>
      </ListStyle>
    </Style>

    <Folder>
      <name>Radio A visible by default</name>
      <description>Select which folder to see</description>
      <styleUrl>#rf</styleUrl>
      <Folder>
      <name>Folder A</name>
      <Placemark>
        <name>Radio A</name>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>-121.9921875, 37.44140625</coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
      </Folder>

      <Folder>
      <name>Folder B</name>
      <visibility>0</visibility>
      <Placemark>
        <name>Radio B</name>
        <visibility>0</visibility>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>-121.9921875, 37.265625</coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
      </Folder>

    </Folder>    
  </Document>
</kml>
```

Reference:
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#listItemType